# Graficar varios vectores en un mismo plano en Python

Tags: python

En una pregunta anterior se aclaró que con el método `quiver()` podemos graficar un vector en un plano, por ejemplo, el siguiente código:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#La clase define in objeto del tipo par ordenado, que se inicializa
#con sus componentes a y b, de la forma binómica de un número complejo:
#(a+ib)
class ParOrdenado:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.real = int(a)
        self.imaginario = int(b)

#La funcion graficar se supone debe tomar esos valores y usarlos para 
#crear un vector que vaya de 0 a el componente respectivo de X y Y
def graficarComp(e):
    # Coordenadas del vector
    x, y = e.real, e.imaginario

    # Limites de la figura
    izda = min(-1, x-1)
    dcha = max(1, x+1)
    abajo = min(-1, y-1)
    arriba = max(1, y+1)

    # El metodo quiver pinta vectores, pero para que salgan de las
    # dimensiones correctas hay que usar los parámetros angles, scale y scale_units

    plt.quiver([x], [y], angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)

    # Pintamos lineas que pasan por el origen de coordenadas
    plt.axhline(0, color='black')
    plt.axvline(0, color='black')

    # Fijamos límites, etiquetas y títulos
    plt.xlim([izda, dcha])
    plt.ylim([abajo, arriba])
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.title('({},{})'.format(e.real,e.imaginario))
    plt.show()


ejemplo = ParOrdenado(1,2)
graficarComp(ejemplo)
```

Pero por ejemplo, si tenemos un conjunto de `ParOrdenado()` como el siguiente:

```
x1=ParOrdenado(1,2)
x2=ParOrdenado(-3,5)
x3=ParOrdenado(2,-5)
```

¿Cómo graficaría los tres vectores en el mismo plano?
De antemano gracias por la ayuda.
(Por cierto, en el post anterior cometí algunos errores al responder y preguntar, soy nuevo en el foro y no supe como eliminar la pregunta, espero comprendan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código que pones se puede adaptar para que reciba una lista de complejos, en lugar de uno solo.

En este caso habrá que eliminar la línea que ponía un título a la gráfica, pues el título eran las coordenadas del complejo representado, pero al ser varios ese título ya no tiene sentido. He decidido entonces que la función retorne el objeto `axis` para que el código que ha llamado a esa función pueda aún manipularla (por ejemplo añadirle un título).

Esta es la nueva versión de la función:

```
def graficarComp(lista):
    # Coordenadas de cada vector de la lista
    # x,y es el origen, u,v el extremo con la flecha
    x = [0]*len(lista)
    y = [0]*len(lista)
    u = []
    v = []
    for vector in lista:
      u.append(vector.real)
      v.append(vector.imaginario)

    # Limites de la figura
    izda = min(-1, min(u)-1)
    dcha = max(1, max(u)+1)
    abajo = min(-1, min(v)-1)
    arriba = max(1, max(v)+1)

    # El metodo quiver pinta vectores, pero para que salgan de las
    # dimensiones correctas hay que usar los parámetros angles, scale y scale_units

    plt.quiver(x, y, u, v,  angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)
    # Pintamos lineas que pasan por el origen de coordenadas
    plt.axhline(0, color='black')
    plt.axvline(0, color='black')

    # Fijamos límites, etiquetas y títulos
    plt.xlim([izda, dcha])
    plt.ylim([abajo, arriba])
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    return plt.gca()
```

Ahora la usaríamos así:

```
x1=ParOrdenado(1,2)
x2=ParOrdenado(-3,5)
x3=ParOrdenado(2,-5)

ax = graficarComp([x1, x2, x3])
ax.set_title("Ejemplo con tres vectores")
plt.show()
```

[image: Tres vectores]

Fíjate que si quieres usarla para un solo vector, aún así tienes que pasarle una lista (pero con un solo elemento en ella):

```
ejemplo = ParOrdenado(1,2)
ax = graficarComp([ejemplo])
ax.set_title("Ejemplo con un vector")
plt.show()
```

[image: Un solo vector]

### Actualización

Si quieres que cada vector sea de un color, se le puede pasar a `quiver()` un parámetro `color` con la lista de colores a usar. Pintará el primer vector con el primer color, el segundo con el siguiente, etc. Si se acaba la lista de colores antes que la lista de vectores, comenzará de nuevo a repetir colores.

Por ejemplo, podemos hacer que nuestro `graficarComp()` reciba la lista de colores como parámetro (con un valor por defecto por si no la recibe):

```
def graficarComp(lista, colores = ["r", "g", "b"]):
    # .... todo sería igual excepto la línea siguiente
    plt.quiver(x, y, u, v,  angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1,
               color=colores)
```

Con ese cambio, la misma llamada de antes a

```
ax = graficarComp([x1, x2, x3])
ax.set_title("Ejemplo con tres vectores")
plt.show()
```

producirá ahora:

[image: Colores]

Si no te gustan los colores por defecto puedes pasarle otros (aquí tienes una [paleta con sus nombres](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/named_colors.html)):

```
ax = graficarComp([x1, x2, x3], ["firebrick", "orange", "salmon"])
```

[image: Otros colores]

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, una última pregunta, si quisiera poner los vectores de un color diferente cada uno, ¿Qué método utilizaría?